Firmware 0.1.34 fails to update on my Lenovo E14
User interface prompts update and when continuing with update the attached image showing 'Update failed'  is displayed within 1 second. Is it the updater or the code being updated that is the issue? More importantly how to fix the issue without 'lifting the bonnet and getting my fingers dirty'.

how is this an Ubuntu problem?

Lenovo advise that it is the operating system updater that is displaying the error and writing the log file and they do not support the operating system, they only support the firmware.  It looks like I am caught between a rock and hard place.

Last 6 lines of sudo update ...Fetched 7,544 kB in 2s (4,126 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
112 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com'
Maybe this is the issue BUT how to correct it

This is a Q&A site and not a forum, comments are for comments from readers to the OP or original poster; and will get removed once details are clearer/corrected in the question. You question provides no release details; which is mandatory to provide help with URLs such as last partial comment, eg. I can open lenovo link provided & see what releases it provide support for, but as I don't know what you're using I can suggest nothing further anyway.  Does it support you unstated release? You mention firmware-updater version but is that package version? as mine is very different. Be specific
